# Using Subtitle Workshop to add subtitles to different locations

Tags: video, avi, subtitles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add subtitles in other places](https://superuser.com/questions/242535/how-to-add-subtitles-in-other-places)

I want to add subtitles to an avi file in other locations besides the bottom. Can this be done in Subtitle Workshop? What programs can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Subtitle Workshop does not hard code subtitles into video files. It just lets you view/edit subtitles. It's your video player which decides where subtitles will be positioned in the video file. For example, in [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/), you have an option to adjust subtitle position up and down on the screen.

If you're looking for a program to show two subtitles at the same time (one at the top, the other one at the bottom), see the answers to this question: [Program to show two subtitle languages at one time.](https://superuser.com/questions/230657/program-to-show-two-subtitle-languages-at-one-time)

<sub>In order to find out how to hard code subtitles into video files, read this question: 
[How do I hard code a movie with subtitles?](https://superuser.com/questions/63736/how-do-i-hard-code-a-movie-with-subtitles)</sub>

Comment: I'm not trying to do any of that. I'm trying to add subtitles to arbitrary positions on the screen, not just at the top and the bottom. I'm using Subtitle Workshop to create the subtitle files and using another program to hardcode them into the video.

Comment: Then your [other question](http://superuser.com/questions/242535/how-to-add-subtitles-in-other-places) has some answers. This is a duplicate.